# Ruby on Rails: Populate view based on database column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm planning on making a table in my view that is a summary of the data I've collected in my database.

For example, what I want to do is count how many times '1' is the response for *gender*, and display that count. I've had trouble making counters in Ruby before, so I wanted to find out how I should do this before I shoot myself in the foot.

I can imagine there is a database function call that sums the the column - but do I perform this action in my view? Or is it something a bit more tricky related to the MVC.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In terms of the MVC Part. Don't do the calculation in the view. Do the calculation in the model or a service class/object and then pass the result to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ActiveRecord::Calculations ?
For example Gender.calculate(:count, :all)

See:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html